# git revert single file tortoise corresponding console command

Tags: ssh, git

I am using tortoise git to operate our git repository on my local machine. However, when I am logged in on a linux machine (ssh) somewhere else, I have to operate git on console.

Locally I use often git tortoise to revert single files to the last commit. What is the corresponding command on console? git revert >commit< reverts the whole repo batch. git revert >file< does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout <commit> -- <files...>
```

If you want to revert to latest commited version, you can omit `<commit>` part.

For example:

```
git checkout master -- README.md
git checkout master -- package.json package-lock.json
```

Note that unlike regular revert, this won't commit reverted files immediately.